# Fix SQL Table with *BOTH* Heap AND Clustered Index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustered-index, heap

Somehow, we have a SQL Server Table with *both* a HEAP and a CLUSTERED index on a table. Is there a way to fix this? e.g. delete the HEAP index by its object ID?

If we drop the Clustered Index, it will create a second HEAP which will be removed when the Clustered Index is recreated. This zombie HEAP index will remain.

[image]

Comment: You probably received a lot of down votes (even thought it is a simple question) because you failed to meet the community's quality standards, which are listed in the help section under [How do I ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The down votes signal:  "...while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, **is poorly researched**, or fails to communicate information."

Comment: @hot2use I guess it's hard to convey I did extensive searching around on the issue (and looking at heaps/clustered keys) - obviously there was no info on it as it was a red herring and that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but the last entry in the table is for a different object/table. `452964740 != 562309263`. So you don't have a heap and a clustered index in the same table.

### Explanation

> A heap is a table without a clustered index.

*Reference: [Heaps (Tables without Clustered Indexes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes)*

So you can't have both a **heap** and a **clustered index** in a table.

### sys.indexes

The definition of sys.indexes is as follows:

```
Column name         Data type           Description
------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object_id           int                 ID of the object to which this index belongs.  
name                sysname             Name of the index. name is unique only within the object.  NULL = Heap  
index_id            int                 ID of the index. index_id is unique only within the object. 
                                        0 = Heap; 
                                        1 = Clustered index; 
                                        > 1 = Nonclustered index   
type                tinyint             Type of index:
                                        0 = Heap
                                        1 = Clustered
                                        2 = Nonclustered
                                        3 = XML
                                        4 = Spatial
                                        5 = Clustered xVelocity memory optimized columnstore index (Reserved for future use.)  
                                        6 = Nonclustered columnstore index  
type_desc            nvarchar(60)       Description of index type:
                                        HEAP
                                        CLUSTERED
                                        NONCLUSTERED
                                        XML
                                        SPATIAL
                                        CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE (Reserved for future use.)
                                        NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE  
is_unique            bit                1 = Index is unique.
                                        0 = Index is not unique.  
data_space_id        int                ID of the data space for this index. Data space is either a filegroup or partition scheme.
                                        0 = object_id is a table-valued function.  
ignore_dup_key       bit                1 = IGNORE_DUP_KEY is ON.
                                        0 = IGNORE_DUP_KEY is OFF.  
is_primary_key        bit               1 = Index is part of a PRIMARY KEY constraint.   
is_unique_constraint  bit               1 = Index is part of a UNIQUE constraint.  
fill_factor           tinyint           > 0 = FILLFACTOR percentage used when the index was created or rebuilt.  
                                        0 = Default value
is_padded             bit               1 = PADINDEX is ON.
                                        0 = PADINDEX is OFF.
is_disabled           bit               1 = Index is disabled.
                                        0 = Index is not disabled.
is_hypothetical       bit               1 = Index is hypothetical and cannot be used directly as a data access path. Hypothetical indexes hold column-level statistics.  
                                        0 = Index is not hypothetical.
allow_row_locks       bit               1 = Index allows row locks.
                                        0 = Index does not allow row locks.
allow_page_locks      bit               1 = Index allows page locks.
                                        0 = Index does not allow page locks.
has_filter            bit               1 = Index has a filter and only contains rows that satisfy the filter definition.
                                        0 = Index does not have a filter.
filter_definition     nvarchar(max)     Expression for the subset of rows included in the filtered index.
                                        NULL for heap or non-filtered index.
```

You will get better results if you join `sys.indexes` with `sys.objects` like this:

```
select so.name, si.* from sys.indexes as si 
    join sys.objects as so 
        on si.object_id = so.object_id
```

You can build on this statement and join with `sys.schemas` to retrieve the (schema-)owner of the table and so forth.

### Reference Material:

- [sys.indexes (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql)
- [sys.objects (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql)
- [Schemas Catalog Views - sys.schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/schemas-catalog-views-sys-schemas)
- [Heaps (Tables without Clustered Indexes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes)

Comment: Thanks - the danger of looking at just a table name and not the full schema name. Interestingly our backend system was also fooled by this second table - deleting this "backup" table fixed the issue.